# AuthAction in yii2

Tags: oauth, yii2

I'm trying to implement yii\authclient\AuthAction's successCallback.

My code looks like this:

```
public function actions()
  {
    return [
      'auth' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
        'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * @param \yii\authclient\ClientInterface $client
   */
  public function successCallback($client)
  {
    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();

    $externalUser = new AuthForm();
    $externalUser->authProvider = $client->getName();
    $externalUser->externalUserId = array_key_exists('id', $attributes) ? $attributes['id'] : null;

    if ($externalUser->validate())
    {
      if ($externalUser->isRegistered())
      {
        $externalUser->login();
        return $this->redirect(['private/index']);
      }
      else
      {
        Yii::$app->session->set( 'signup/authProvider', $externalUser->authProvider );
        Yii::$app->session->set( 'signup/attributes'  , $attributes );

        return $this->redirect(['site/signup']);
      }    
    }
  }
```

How can I call successCallback? I want to call the auth method. But I am not able to do this?

Comment: `$externalUser->login();` You want to call login function but user do not login ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is working fine, but you did not permit for the action of `auth` to be accessed. Make sure you allow `auth` in your behaviours of your controller. Something like:

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors [ 'access' ] = [
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => [ 'auth' ],
                'allow'   => true,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will run `successCallback` when Auth server response successful.
You must config authcollection (collection config of auth server)

```
'components' => [
    'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            'google' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOpenId'
            ],
            'facebook' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                'clientId' => 'facebook_client_id',
                'clientSecret' => 'facebook_client_secret',
            ],
            // etc.
        ],
    ]
    ...
]
```

Default: Yii2 authclient support some openid, oauth, oauth2 provider:

- [[\yii\authclient\clients\Facebook|Facebook]].
- [[yii\authclient\clients\GitHub|GitHub]].
- Google (via [[yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOpenId|OpenID]] and  [[yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth|OAuth]]).
- [[yii\authclient\clients\LinkedIn|LinkedIn]].
- [[yii\authclient\clients\Live|Microsoft Live]].
- [[yii\authclient\clients\Twitter|Twitter]].
- [[yii\authclient\clients\VKontakte|VKontakte]].
- Yandex (via [[yii\authclient\clients\YandexOpenId|OpenID]] and [[yii\authclient\clients\YandexOAuth|OAuth]]).

There's ready to use [[yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice]] widget to use in views:

```
<?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
     'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'],
     'popupMode' => false,
]) ?>
```

For more infomation: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/tree/master/docs/guide

Goodluck and have fun!